# Jenkins poll scm option to ignore certain files changes

Tags: version-control, build, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

Forewarning: Its possible I don't understand how Jenkins works completely, and I am pretty novice in general, so please bear with me.

I'm working on a Jenkins build script for a project, and one aspect of the job is that it needs to poll scm nightly (using build triggers->Poll SCM) and then edit the "version" config file with an incremented build/version number then push that to the bitbucket repository. However, I don't want Jenkins to consider the version config file when polling the SCM for changes. As in, if the only change is a version update, ignore that and do not do the build-- otherwise it will always do builds nightly.

Thanks and if I am approaching this the completely wrong way please let me know!

Comment: Please be li'l clear about what scenario are you talking about. Where is the version config file? Do you want the updated version config file to be checked-in? When do you want to ignore the version update? If possible please write down the steps of what do you actually want.

Answer (score 8):

Under `Additional Behaviors`, you will find `Polling ignores commits from certain users`. List there all users that, if they are the commiters, the build will not be allowed to run.

Comment: super useful features i did not notice before you mentioned them